# Uncaught ReferenceError: firebase is not defined - Google Chrome Extension, Background.js

Tags: firebase, google-chrome-extension

I am trying to read/write data to a Firebase database, but I can't seem to import Firebase correctly into my Google Chrome Extension. All help is appreciated.

I try to import it in `popup.html`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <style>
      button {
        height: 30px;
        width: 30px;
        outline: none;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <button id="startButton"></button>
    <button id="stopButton"></button>
    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.2.2/firebase.js"></script>
    <script src="popup.js"></script>


</body>
</html>
```

I then call it in `background.js` which is where I get the error: `Uncaught ReferenceError: firebase is not defined`

```
var config = {
  apiKey: "xxxx",
  databaseURL: "xxxx",
  storageBucket: "xxx"
};

firebase.initializeApp(config); //Error
...
```

and I set my rules up in `manifest.json`

```
{
    "name": "Company Websites",
    "version": "1.0",
    "description": "Build an Extension!",
    "background": {
        "scripts": ["background.js"],
        "persistent": false
      },
      "content_scripts": [
        {
          "matches": ["<all_urls>","http://*/*", "https://*/*"],
          "js": ["scrapeSearch.js"]
        }
      ],
      "page_action": {
        "default_popup": "popup.html"
      },
      "content_security_policy": "script-src 'self' https://www.gstatic.com/ https://*.firebaseio.com https://www.googleapis.com; object-src 'self'; connect-src 'self' wss://*.firebaseio.com;",
      "permissions": ["tabs","storage","declarativeContent", "activeTab"],
    "manifest_version": 2
  }
```

Thanks in advance,

Comment: The background script runs in its own separate hidden background page, not related  to the browser_action (or page_action) popup. Look for examples of using firebase in the background script. In short, you'll need to load its script in your background page.

Comment: This is the guide i tried to follow: https://www.originate.com/thinking/stories/building-a-chrome-extension-using-firebase-real-time-database/. Maybe i missed something but I thought I had followed it successfully - but apparently not.

Comment: This tutorial doesn't contain a detailed description or a final project so it's better to find another one. I can only guess you can try downloading firebase.js into extension directory manually and then declaring it in manifest.json before "background.js" so it's loaded in the background context.

Comment: It turns out the the method was correct, but this is to get Firebase working on popup.js (not background.js). So configure in Popup.js.  I now send messages between tabs in order to trigger Firebase functions.